# How to program call divert settings on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

Does anyone know how to get/set the call divert settings in codes running on Windows mobile 5/6? I am new to windows mobile development and wonder if there is anyway to do it using C# and .NET CF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean call forwarding?  In general terms, the [Telephony API (TAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899558.aspx) is used for programmatically controlling the phone interface.  Call forwarding is specifically handled by [TSPI_lineForward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451032.aspx).

Microsoft does not offer any built-in or SDK tools for managed developers to use TAPI, and the structures TAPI uses are cumbersome and difficult to P/Invoke.  There are a some [3rd-party libraries](http://tapi.codeplex.com/) that do provide some level of TAPI interaction that you might also investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. I do mean call forwarding and what I would like to do is to have a simple application, perhaps with only 2 big buttons. When pressed, one should forward the incoming calls to my work phone and the other should forward them to my home phone. Being a (desktop application) developer myself of course I would like to have created my own solution for it. I once tried the TAPI wrapper provided by Microsoft to try to dial the GSM codes and it just won't work in codes when I tried to 'dial' the GSM codes... Perhaps I should spend more time studying the TAPI on mobile devices.